# Wordpress : How to programatically return the number of plugins that need update

Tags: wordpress, plugins, numbers, upgrade

Is there a way to return the number that appears in the little red bubble next to "plugins" when some of them need an update ?

I'm using Wordpress 3.0.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a routine in `wp-admin/includes/update.php` line 155 (in WP 3.0.5) called `get_plugin_updates()`. It returns an array of plugins with update's available. `count(get_plugin_update())` should do it for you.